# System time shows same value everytime

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

When user click on `CTRL + S` then it should display current time.
For the first time it will show current time but next time it will show as previous one
here is the code:

```
var newtime;
$.save('S', function () {
    newtime = '@System.DateTime.Now.ToString("t")';
    autoSave("Last saved at " + '@DateTime.Now.ToString("t")');
});
```

Tried both thing still get same output..I got in `newtime=10:37` everytime..something is missing over there?

Comment: Is it C# language????

Comment: it seems like javascript ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching the DateTime value from server using Razor syntax in this javascript code. It will always be the same everytime this code is executed.

You need to use-

```
var newtime;
$.save('S', function () {
    var currentdate = new Date();
    newtime = currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
    autoSave("Last saved at " + newtime);
});
```

Comment: I am glad it helped, kindly mark accept the answer, so that others facing the same issue can use this answer undoubtedly :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript datetime function instead of C# because the DateTime.Now.ToString("t") is only executed on server side, not on the client side. Try this instead:

```
$.save('S', function () {
    var d = new Date();
    newTime = d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes();
    autoSave("Last saved at " + newTime);
});
```